# Importing a MySQL Table from one server to another server

Tags: mysql, import, export, mysql-workbench

I need to import the table from One MySQL server to another MySQL server. The requirement looks pretty simple but i tried two ways and unable to import the data. Please find the below details and methods I tried to import the data.

> 1. We have an existing table in Server A with Engine Type as **MyISAM**, No primary key and contains duplicate records.
> 2. Now, We need to export this table into a new MySQL server (Server B) but the new MYSQL DB has some rules.
>
>    - Engine should be **InnoDB**
>    - Every table should contains a primary key.

The below ways i tried to import and failed.

**Method 1:-**

```
Exported the data from server A with Outfile command using MySQL Workbench 
and tried to import with Infile command but due to the "mandatory primary key" validation all the 
rows were not inserted. So to avoid this added an incremental column in new table and tried to 
import but again it's failed due to the no.of columns mismatch error
```

**Method 2:-**

```
Configured both the servers in MySQL WorkBench and exported the table in Server A
with MANAGEMENT-> Data Export and tried to Import with MANAGEMENT-> Data Import/Restore
but due to the engines mismatch between the two tables again it's failed to import the data. 
(Tried with Dump project folder and self contained folder).
```

AFAIK, Now I'm left with only one option (which I don't want to do due to the huge data).

- Export the data as a CSV file and Import it by using Table Data Import Wizard.

Please guide me is there any other option to import the Data.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to add the new auto inc column to your source table (and add the primary key also, to check if there's no problem). To make this complete you can also convert the table to the InnoDB engine and have it so prepared to be copied over with the least friction.